# Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer

Tags: checkbox, asp.net-core-mvc, invalidoperationexception

[image]I want to get Id of an entity which is an int type value; user will check/uncheck the checkbox, so I've converted that into boolean type. But I'm getting error. Here is the code-

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <form asp-action="ReturnProduct" asp-route-id="@Model[i].HiddenPKVMId"
              onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Convert.ToBoolean(Model[i].ProductVMName)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].HiddenPKVMId" />
        </form>
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the error you are getting? Without it, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Seems you are using ajax submit the form, can you show us the codes, the error message as well.

Comment: Edit: I've attached the error screenshot. And it's not about the form submit because I'm not getting expected output which I should get before the submission.

Answer (score 0):

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer

Seems that you didn't set property in your class. Try something like this:

Use

```
public class Product
{
    public int HiddenPKVMId{ get; set; }
    public string ProductVMName { get; set; }
}
```

instead of

```
public class Product
{
    public int HiddenPKVMId;
    public string ProductVMName;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Valkyrie_30, is this the case?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it wasn't the case. I found out another way.